# Find element by xpath failing with certain values

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

Using selenium webdriver and C#, when I attempt to find a element using the code below and the `defaultLocationID` is in the range `1-9` (i.e a single digit) it fails.

However if the `defaultLocationID` is `10` or above (i.e. multiple digits) it succeeds.

```
_webDriver.FindElement(By.XPath("//input[@value='" + defaultLocationID + "']")).Click();
```

Has anyone experienced this and come up with a workaround, other than insuring the the `ID` is 10 or above?

The element I am trying to find is:

```
<li><input type="checkbox" value="2"> LocationName</li>
```

In response to Würgspaß answer I have tried the following:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(_webDriver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20));
IWebElement element = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.XPath("//input[@value='2']")));
_webDriver.FindElement(By.XPath("//input[@value='2']")).Click();
commonFunctions.ClickButtonOrLink(_webDriver, "save-btn");
```

This fails with:

```
OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverTimeoutException : Timed out after 20 seconds
```

Also attempted:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(_webDriver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20));
IWebElement myDynamicElement = wait.Until<IWebElement>((d) =>
{
        return d.FindElement(By.XPath("//input[@value='2']"));
});
_webDriver.FindElement(By.XPath("//input[@value='2']")).Click();
commonFunctions.ClickButtonOrLink(_webDriver, "save-btn");
```

This fails with the same error as before.

Replacing the value with 11 both pass successfully.

Comment: Are your values in the form "01", " 02" ?

Comment: You need to provide the relevant HTML of the page or a link to it so we can help you.

Comment: I've added the html element above, and the values are is in the form "1".

What I'm struggling to understand is why it works is if the value is 15 but not 2!

Comment: What is the error (message). Something like `NoSuchElementException` or rather something like "not visible" or "cannot be interacted with" or even a `StaleElementReferenceException`??

Comment: The error is:
    OpenQA.Selenium.ElementNotVisibleException : element not visible

Answer (score 0):

See the Selenium documentation on how to use [explicit waits](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#explicit-and-implicit-waits).

The Java way of waiting for an element to be clickable is like this (in C# it should be similar):

```
//30s timeout, use timeout not sleep
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30); 
By xpath = By.xpath("//input[@value='" + defaultLocationID + "']");
//wait for element to be clickable, then click
WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(xpath));
```

Alternatively wait for visibility:

```
WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(xpath));
```

If it is not visible, don't use it.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I tried both suggestions with no change in behavior, see edit in the original post.

Comment: @Colin As I said: If it is not visible (and does not become visible after a while) **you cannot use** the element. You can try to execute some JavaScript to make it visible. But this is an entirely different story.